# Pandas - Is it possible to use a column as an argument in string indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I'm extracting portions of the string to their own column. The MRN_position column holds the position of the specific word in the string for that row.I need the end part of the string index method to be dynamic but it returns NaN. I expect to see the sub-string extracted as the output.

```
# Hard coded
df['raw'].str[95:117]

# What I need
df['raw'].str[95:df['MRN_position']]

# Main Dataframe
    raw                                     MRN_position
1   Encounter: 12345678 Status: Open A...   117
2   1 Open 11/11/2019 BEC...                -1
4   2 Open 11/11/2019 BEC...                -1
6   Encounter: 24561879 Status: Open A...   117
7   1 Open 11/11/2019 ZRE...                -1

# Current output result
1     NaN
2     NaN
4     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Instead use `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['raw'][95:x['MRN_position']], axis=1)
```

or just list comprehension:

```
[x[95:y] for x,y in zip(df['raw'], df['MRN_position'])]
```